# why Is blkdiag showing error?

Tags: matlab, octave

This is the code that I wrote to my octave console:

```
disp("Hello World"); 

n=4; 

B=[1,1,1,1;2,2,2,2;3,3,3,3;4,4,4,4];

R=eye(7); 

for i=1:n 

   gamma(i)=blkdiag(eye(n-i),B,eye(i-1))

end; 

gamma(i)
```

But, I am getting this error:

error: my_script.my: A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I

Any help. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: `blkdiag` gives you a 2d array. `gamma(i)` is a scalar. You can't fit a 2d array in the space meant for a scalar. You probably want `gamma(:,:,i) = ...`.

Comment: @beaker ok, suppose I want 4 [7x7] matrices(gamma(1),gamma(2),gamma(3),gamma(4)), then what modification should I make? Shall i write 'gamma(:,:,i)' as you wrote?thanks by the way

Comment: Yes. Then you access the first one as `gamma(:,:,1)`.

Comment: @beaker and thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by beaker, to index the matrices, we need to use another indexing element. Therefore, the right syntax to get the syntax obviated is:

```
gamma(:,:,i)
```

instead of

```
gamma(i)
```